# Applying squeeze theorem to conditionally convergent series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose that the series ∑_n≥1(a_n) converges conditionally. Then by the Riemann Series theorem, for any real number L there exists a rearrangement of a_n(let's call it b_n) that converges to L. For a finite sum, ∑(a_n)=∑(b_n), for any rearrangement b_n. But if I apply the squeeze theorem, since I have that ∑(a_n)≤∑(b_n)≤∑(a_n), and ∑(a_n) converges to a number A, shouldn't I have ∑(b_n) converging to A? Doesn't this mean that the infinite sum of any rearrangent b_n converges to A. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

How did you know that for a finite sum $\sum a_n=\sum b_n$? To see why this is wrong in general, consider $a_n=\frac{1}{n^2}$ from $n=1$ to $n=10$. Now, we have:

$$\sum_1^5 a_n=\frac{5269}{3600}$$

Consider $b_n$ where the first 5 terms and the others right after them are swapped, so we get

$$\sum_1^5 b_n=\sum_6^{10} a_n=\frac{547129}{6350400}$$

Thus, your initial step was wrong. Done.

Edit:

After seeing your comment, I shall reflect on what you said.

Technically, yes, in the case where a rearrangement is as you said, then you are correct. It will converge to $A$. The proof is way simpler by just saying that $|\sum_1^N a_n - A|=|\sum_1^N b_n - A|$ since $\sum_1^Na_n=\sum_1^N b_n$ since all you did was rearrange the terms before $N$.

However, I must note that this isn't exactly what was done in the proof of the Riemann series theorem. As you can see in this [proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem), the rearrangement is done while choosing terms arbitrarily, since the first $N$ terms can be negative while we are allowed to pick the positive terms which might be starting from $N+1$ for example, all of course for some $N$.

You might have gotten the definition of a rearrangement wrong as it isn't what you described in your comment. All it means is that there exists a bijective mapping between $a_n$ and $b_n$ terms. That is, there is a bijection $\sigma: \mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ such that $b_n=a_{\sigma (n)}$

I hope this helps.

Comment: By b_n I mean taking the first N terms of a_n and rearranging it. So for the example you gave, it would be invalid as the rearrangement b_n takes value of a_n after N=5.

Comment: Oh, I see, I will make an edit.

Comment: But isn't it still invalid? The sum of b_n to N=10 will equal to the sum of a_n to N=10, right?

Comment: I have edited my post to answer your questions.